# Python 3 - Selenium - scraping data from nested divs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm reasonably new to python and I'm trying to check which div class appears first on a page. I've done this with table rows but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to do this with divs.

What I'm trying to determine is whether the latest update is an email sent `<div class="EMAIL SENT">` or a notes added `<div class="Notes">`. The most recent item will appear first from the top, but other actions may have taken place since then, for example, `<div class="Updated">`

I've not managed to write any code to do this or event get close, but in my head I imagine it to work like this.

```
for sub_div_classes in browser.find_element_by_class_name('cb'):
    classname = ~check name of sub_div_class
    if classname = "EMAIL SENT":
        class_info = browser.find_element_by_class_name('plus_header_Additional_info').text
        print(class_info) ¬output: EMAIL SENT&nbsp;:Email sent on 20-03-2016 00:22:09 by [REDACTED]
        trigger_1()
    if classname = "Notes":
        trigger_2()
    ~move on to next div class in list
```

Below is the page code I'm trying to work with. I'd be really appreciative of any advice or assistance anyone can provide.

```
<div class="cb" style="margin:5px 0 0 0;">
                              <div class="Updated">
                               <div class="plus_header_Additional_info">Updated&nbsp;:Incident Updated on 20-03-2016 00:22:52 by User = [REDACTED]

                                 <a href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2_0', 'imageDivLink2_0');" id="imageDivLink2_0"><img src="images/minus.png" style="float:right;"></a> 
                               </div>
                                   <div class="plus_content" style="display: block;" id="contentDivImg2_0">
                               <div> 
                                             Assigned to STRIKE1, 
 by User = [REDACTED].
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="Updated">
                               <div class="plus_header_Additional_info">Updated&nbsp;:PEND CLIENT STRIKE - 1 added on 20-03-2016 00:22:36 by [REDACTED]. 
                                 <a href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2_1', 'imageDivLink2_1');" id="imageDivLink2_1"><img src="images/minus.png" style="float:right;"></a> 
                               </div>
                                   <div class="plus_content" style="display: block;" id="contentDivImg2_1">
                               <div> 
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="EMAIL SENT">
                               <div class="plus_header_Additional_info">EMAIL SENT&nbsp;:Email sent on 20-03-2016 00:22:09 by [REDACTED] 
                                 <a href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2_2', 'imageDivLink2_2');" id="imageDivLink2_2"><img src="images/minus.png" style="float:right;"></a> 
                               </div>
                                   <div class="plus_content" style="display: block;" id="contentDivImg2_2">
                               <div> 
                                            To :- [NAME]@[DOMAIN].CO.UK Subject: Ticket - [IN-000999999] Description : Dear User,

[REDACTED]
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="Updated">
                               <div class="plus_header_Additional_info">Updated&nbsp;:Incident Updated on 12-03-2016 10:56:15 by User = [REDACTED]

                                 <a href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2_3', 'imageDivLink2_3');" id="imageDivLink2_3"><img src="images/minus.png" style="float:right;"></a> 
                               </div>
                                   <div class="plus_content" style="display: block;" id="contentDivImg2_3">
                               <div> 
                                             Status:- PROGRESSING changed to PEND CLIENT, 
 Assigned to SOFTWARE DEPLOYED, 
 by User = [REDACTED].
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                              <div class="Notes">
                               <div class="plus_header_Additional_info">Notes&nbsp;:Notes Added on 12-03-2016 10:55:53 by [REDACTED]. 
                                 <a href="javascript:toggle2('contentDivImg2_4', 'imageDivLink2_4');" id="imageDivLink2_4"><img src="images/minus.png" style="float:right;"></a> 
                               </div>
                                   <div class="plus_content" style="display: block;" id="contentDivImg2_4">
                               <div> 
                                            <textarea id="notes4" name="notes1" cols="" class="emailForm_input1" style="width: 97%; overflow: hidden; word-wrap: break-word; resize: horizontal; height: 237px;" readonly="readonly">Hello,
[REDACTED]
</textarea>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                                </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Try beautiful soup, it does that. Just do soup.find("div"), find returns a single div element (and the first occurrence).

Comment: @iamaziz, that would find the div with `class="Updated">` which is not what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `or` with an xpath:

```
.xpath("//div[@class='Notes' or @class='EMAIL SENT']")[0]
```

If Notes comes first you will get Notes and vice versa.

If we change a bit of your html snippet like below, adding some text to `<div class="EMAIL SENT">in email` and changing a later tag class to `<div class="Notes">in notes`:

We can see using lxml how it works:

```
In [13]: from lxml.etree import fromstring, HTMLParser

In [14]: xml = fromstring(html, HTMLParser())

In [15]: xml.xpath("//div[@class='Notes' or @class='EMAIL SENT']")
Out[15]: [<Element div at 0x7f96598d4ea8>, <Element div at 0x7f96598d4ef0>]

In [16]: xml.xpath("//div[@class='Notes' or @class='EMAIL SENT']")[0].text
Out[16]: 'in email\n                               '

In [17]: xml.xpath("//div[@class='Notes' or @class='EMAIL SENT']")[1].text
Out[17]: 'in notes\n
```

So with selenium you want to just find the element by xpath.

Comment: Thanks for your response Padraic. That does help me understand more fully. 

I've written the following bit of code to test this but I'm receiving the error of 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_path'


`    note_base_table = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('cb')`
`    for note_base_rows in note_base_table.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Notes' or @class='EMAIL SENT']"):`
`        print(note_base_rows)`

A similar method worked when I was pulling data from a table and I used `from table_rows in base_table.find_element_by_tag_name('tr'):`

Clearly I'm missing something

Comment: You should be using `note_base_rows.xpath...` you are looping over `note_base_table` and using `note_base_table.xpath` that is the list not each element in iteration.